# О, полку 100k прибыло :)

Tags: обсуждение, вехи, поздравление

Заметил, что [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor) перешагнул 100k - не могу не поздравить :)
Дальнейших успехов!

P.S. Если неофициальное поздравление оффтоп - удалю...

P.P.S. Для, так сказать, юбиляра :) - будут писать о заморских подарках - не верьте, будут только обещать. По крайней мере мне уже больше года обещают :)

Comment: Не оффтоп (: Подарков не будет, да. Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям ٩(◕‿◕｡)۶

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, почему? ((

Comment: @Qwertiy с прошлым поставщиком мерча расстались, а нового пока не ищут. Ни пользователям, ни модераторам ничего не рассылают больше. И не ясно, будут ли вообще когда-либо.

Comment: Прочитал как "пОлку 100к прибило". Думаю, что за полка, какой контроллер, что значит "прибило" и что за 100к, рпс что ли, так это мало...

Comment: Harry, Suvitruf, большое спасибо!

Comment: О,  поздравляю со взятием рубежа! Восхищён универсализмом.

Comment: @Igor От всей души поздравляю Вас с этим невероятным достижением ) Вы потрясающий специалист. Желаю Вам побольше интересных задач и захватывающих проектов. )

Comment: @MBo, Denis640Kb - От души благодарю вас и всех остальных, кто присоединился к поздравлениям Harry!

Comment: @Igor Тоже поздравляю! Главное не останавливайтесь на достигнутом, ruSO тоже нужен отечественный  Jon Skeet ;D !

Comment: @Igor, присоединяюсь к поздравлениям)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, n199a Спасибо! Что нам Джон Скит :)! Я начал свою деятельность на SO, ответив на вопрос, на который он не смог ответить - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052200/why-does-this-threading-approach-not-work/3102605#3102605

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica был у нас свой Джон Скит, да вот политика партии его сдула... как и некоторых других.

Comment: @Igor признайтесь, это все ваши гномики вам помогли :) Поздравляю!

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо! Признаюсь. Все сделали гномики. Я тут вообще ни при чем. :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358195/865952

Comment: Куда @Igor делся?... Странно, что он удалил свой профиль...

Answer (score 11):

От лица команды проекта присоединяюсь к поздравлениям! [@Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor), большое спасибо за ваш вклад в развитие русскоязычной базы знаний по программированию. Надеемся увидеть вас среди тех, кто доберется до четверти миллиона баллов =)