# Так когда же нужно использовать [поздравление]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, мета

Недавно участник [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) набрал 100k репутации. Был задан, вопрос с меткой [поздравление](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), и сотрудник [@NicolasChabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) убрал метку поздравление и поставил метку [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8).

Так в каких же вопросах надо ставить метку поздравление?

Comment: Nicolas Chabanovsky не модератор, он сотрудник.

Comment: Там один вопрос с этой меткой, нет? =)

Comment: Да никогда не надо, она же пустая

Comment: Как сердце подсказывает

Comment: @0xdb [юзер интерфейс не совсем солидарен](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UyKO.png)

Comment: @dIm0n, она не пустая: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10242/178988.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, видимо "неотвеченные" смотрел. Но можно снять оттуда и удалить за ненадобностью :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ UI пишут разработчики. Их интересует - как впихнуть туда две иконки,  а надо ли они там, или кой их смысл, этими вопросами они не задаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему скромному мнению метка [поздравление](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) актуальна для сообщений, адресованных какому-то конкретному участнику (или может быть небольшой группе, хотя пока сложно придумать для этого пример). Если же сообщение описывает важную контрольную точку для всего сообщества, то здесь уместна метка [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8). В некоторых ситуациях их разумно использовать совместно, например:

- первый участник, набравший 100, 200, 500, 1000 килореп
- первый участник, получивший золотые метки по N популярным меткам
- первый участник, сообщение которого набрало 100, 200, 500 ... голосов "за"
- ...